# How to get html element inside button?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<button type="button" name="abc" id="abc" class="bp" onmouseover="this.className = 'bp bph'" onmouseout="this.className = 'bp'" onclick="oCV_NS_.promptAction('finish')" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;font-size:9pt">
<span tabindex="0">GENERATE REPORT</span>

</button>
```

I want to click this button and tried few codes but nothing worked
tried:

`driver.find_element_by_id("abc").click();`

`driver.find_element(By.ID, "abc")`

`element_by_name` also tried

Comment: You question appears confusing to me. Are you trying to get the HTML element inside the button (as the question title states) or are you trying to click the button (as the question body text states)?

Comment: My ultimate aim is to click the button

Comment: If you can provide more of the HTML or the actual website we will be able to help more...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and also check if button is not part of iframe:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
button= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "abc")))
button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am getting "TimeoutException" when using the code

Comment: Can you provide your site ?

Answer (score 0):

Try use with the below `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='abc']/span").click()
```